# Understanding Stash Variables

Tags: stash

I'm using Stash 2.3.6 beta. Can somebody explain why this works:

```
{exp:stash:set name="var1"}no{/exp:stash:set}
{exp:stash:set name="var1"}yes{/exp:stash:set}
{exp:stash:get name="var1"}
```

Where I get "yes" as output.

But this does not:

```
{exp:stash:set name="var1"}no{/exp:stash:set}
{exp:channel:entries channel="promos" limit="1"}
    {exp:stash:set name="var1" replace="yes"}yes{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{exp:stash:get name="var1"}
```

Where I get "no" as output, but expect "yes".

I'm guessing it has to do with the parse order, and that channel:entries happens after everything outside of it is parsed. I looked at the parse order docs (The Template Engine), and it looks like channel:entries are processed on step 15, module and plugin tags. Not sure where Stash gets processed.

But, speaking of which, I did try adding process="end" to the get. That got me a funky looking output:  {357b280a38bad6479603b312799efcb0422985159}

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't have the ability to test this right now, but i imagine you would want to set `{exp:stash:set name="var1"}no{/exp:stash:set}` to `{exp:stash:set replace="yes" name="var1"}no{/exp:stash:set}`

Comment: Yeah, I've actually already tried that @philecker. Still no go. Thanks though.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your channel entries with `exp:stash:set`

Comment: What's the main goal of overwriting the same variable exactly? I see what you're trying to do but can't understand why as I don't know the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such seemingly random strings can be [a symptom of the Stash extension not being activated](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/4995/141). Worth a check.

Those strings are used by Stash as placeholders getting replaced by the stash extension. If the stash extension is not activated, they never get replaced.

Comment: Important safety tip, boys and girls: read the installation instructions. (d'Oh!) Thanks @JeromeCoupe.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. We've all been there

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a parse order thing, the get is parsed before the second set, since it is within a channel entries tag pair. But this should work:

```
{exp:stash:set name="var1"}no{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:channel:entries limit="1"}
  {exp:stash:set name="var1" replace="yes"}yes{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
  {exp:stash:get name="var1"}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

But in general, you won't get very far with setting and getting data within the same template. That's why the [template partials approach](http://eeinsider.com/articles/template-partials-using-stash/) sets data in the base template and then gets it in an embedded template.

Comment: Thanks @aelvan. I tried exactly your code, and got this: {6ee64145dfa4ae5926a9c326266d5954317291731}. Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me.. But I know that error, just can't remember what it's all about. :/ What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: PHP 5.3.20. EE Core 2.5.5.

Comment: Is the stash extension enabled ?

Comment: Yeah, the extension, that's it. :) Try it, NotoriousWebmaster. Been burnt by that myself.